# How to get last insert id when using sub query in Kohana

Tags: subquery, kohana, lastinsertid

How do I return the correct $insert_id when using a sub query in Kohana?

I'm using the query method to return $insert_id and $affected_rows. It returns the correct value for $affected_rows but returns '1' for $insert_id which is incorrect.

Query below:

```
$sub = DB::select('id', 'username', 'email', 'lastVisitDate')->from('jos_users');

$qry_migrate_users = DB::insert('temp_users', array('old_id', 'username', 'email_work', 'last_login'))->select($sub);

list($insert_id, $affected_rows) = $qry_migrate_users->execute($this->conn_target);
```

Comment: Note that MySQL returns last insert id for the *first* inserted row.

Comment: That's what I suspected but wasn't sure. I surmise that because I'm using the subquery that there's no way to actually return the last insert id then?

Comment: Of course, you can select new rows from `temp_users` using `old_id` values and get max id. But why do you need last insert id?

Comment: The insert id is stored in another table to reference when doing further migrations of new users from the jos_users table. I should have worded my response better. I can get the last insert id but wondered why it didn't work through Kohana's suggested method. As you said, it is returning the correct value for the first row. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL returns only last insert id and affected rows. there is only one way to do what you want - execute your sub-select to array, and using foreach do single inserts. But it's a lilte bit slower operation! Or after inserting do something like that:

```
SELECT id FROM temp_users WHERE email IN (select email from jos_users)
```

You might understand the logic